# For loop while time.Now() is reached

Tags: go

Is it possible in Golang to increment a date in a for loop by a given date variable till it reached the current date/ time.Now()

```
// Start date
t, _ := time.Parse(time.RFC3339, "2018-07-19T12:25:10.8584224+02:00")

// Current date
ct := time.Now()

for d := t; d.Day() == ct.Day(); d = d.AddDate(0, 0, 1) {
    // Print all days between start date and current date 
    fmt.Println(d)
}
```

I expect that variable d prints out all dates (with time etc.) till it reached the current date

Comment: Yes. Are you having some issue with this code?

Comment: Yes, unfortunately it doesn't print anything at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

according to godoc: https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Time.Day

`func (t Time) Day() int`

Day returns the day of the month specified by t.

So comparing d.Day() and ct.Day() is not the right approaches. What if today is "2019-01-01",and you start time is "2018-12-23"?

The right way to compare two time.Time is https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Time.After

```
func (t Time) After(u Time) bool
func (t Time) Before(u Time) bool
```

After reports whether the time instant t is after u.
Before reports whether the time instant t is before u.

So @Alex Pliutau's solution is more in common use. But need more careful with today.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    t, _ := time.Parse(time.RFC3339, "2009-11-02T12:25:10.8584224+02:00")

    // truncate to 0:0:0
    t = t.Truncate(24 * time.Hour)
    fmt.Println("start time is:", t)

    // Current date truncate to 0:0:0
    ct := time.Now().Truncate(24 * time.Hour)
    fmt.Println("now is:", ct)
    fmt.Println("---------------")

    // for t.Before(ct) {  //if you don't want to print the date of today
    for !t.After(ct) {
        // Print all days between start date and current date
        fmt.Println(t.Format("2006-01-02 15:04:05"))
        t = t.AddDate(0, 0, 1)
    }
}
```

Output:

```
start time is: 2009-11-02 02:00:00 +0200 +0200
now is: 2009-11-10 00:00:00 +0000 UTC
---------------
2009-11-02 02:00:00
2009-11-03 02:00:00
2009-11-04 02:00:00
2009-11-05 02:00:00
2009-11-06 02:00:00
2009-11-07 02:00:00
2009-11-08 02:00:00
2009-11-09 02:00:00
2009-11-10 02:00:00
```

https://play.golang.org/p/iMr7M5W9K4N

Answer (score 1):

get the loop condition right and..

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Hello, playground")
    t, _ := time.Parse(time.RFC3339, "2018-07-19T12:25:10.8584224+02:00")

    // Current date
    ct := time.Now()

    for d := t; d.Day() >= ct.Day(); d = d.AddDate(0, 0, 1) {
        // Print all days between start date and current date
        fmt.Println(d)
    }
}

Hello, playground
2018-07-19 12:25:10.8584224 +0200 +0200
2018-07-20 12:25:10.8584224 +0200 +0200
2018-07-21 12:25:10.8584224 +0200 +0200
2018-07-22 12:25:10.8584224 +0200 +0200
2018-07-23 12:25:10.8584224 +0200 +0200
2018-07-24 12:25:10.8584224 +0200 +0200
2018-07-25 12:25:10.8584224 +0200 +0200
2018-07-26 12:25:10.8584224 +0200 +0200
2018-07-27 12:25:10.8584224 +0200 +0200
2018-07-28 12:25:10.8584224 +0200 +0200
2018-07-29 12:25:10.8584224 +0200 +0200
2018-07-30 12:25:10.8584224 +0200 +0200
2018-07-31 12:25:10.8584224 +0200 +0200
```

https://play.golang.org/p/yRBTUZKfseG

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comments, you need to actually tell it to `Format` the date to something of value:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    start, err := time.Parse("2006-1-2", "2018-1-1")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    for d := start; d.Month() == start.Month(); d = d.AddDate(0, 0, 1) {
        fmt.Println(d.Format("2006-1-2"))
    }
}
```

Here's a simpler version of your code (I used a custom time format, cause I didn't wanna edit the RFC syntax, but ultimately it's the same thing) = I'm also iterating Month for brevity.

Answer (score 0):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    t, _ := time.Parse(time.RFC3339, "2018-07-19T12:25:10.8584224+02:00")

    ct := time.Now()

    for t.Before(ct) {
        fmt.Println(t)
        t.AddDate(0, 0, 1)
    }
}
```